# get keys from the nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking for a function that can mutate my data i.e array of object with a nested object. It will include keys that have object/array values (it should only include keys with immediate string/number/boolean values).

**Example**

```
[
{
  id: 1,
  person1: {
    firstname: "test1",
    lastname: 'singh',
    address: {
        state: "maharashtra",
    }
  }
},
{
  id: 2,
  person2: {
    firstname: "test2",
    lastname: 'rathod',
    address: {
        state: "kerala",
    }
  }
},
{
  id: 3, 
  person3: {
    firstname: "test3",
    lastname: 'gokale',
    address: {
        state: "Tamilnadu",
    }
  }
}
```

]

**Expected output**

```
[
{
  title: 'person1',
  value: 'person.id'
},
{
    title: 'person1',
    value: 'person.firstname'
},
{
    title: 'person1',
    value: 'person.lastname'
},
{
    title: 'person1',
    value: 'person.address'
},
{
    title: 'person1',
    value: 'person.address.state'
},
...sameforOthers
```

]

Basically, I need a function that will get an array and will return an array of objects as a given above as expected output

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is `person.address` in the output if "It also shouldn't include keys that have object/array values"

Comment: Does `id` numbering restart on the second person?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking for. You have also failed to provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: hey @Nick , we can skip the id I have updated the question and expected output

Comment: @RAVIsingh but you haven't answered my question about `person.address`...

Comment: @Nick so, as per the backend model which I am working on, a person can be an object or it can be an array. person object is just an example. I thought to use Object.keys which will work for both arrays and object

Comment: But you say in the question "It also shouldn't include keys that have object/array values" and yet you have the address in the output even though it has an object as its value...

Comment: @Nick thanks for pointing that out, I just misspelled it. I have updated the question.
the nested object will be either object or an array to iterate over I am thinking to use Object.keys with type check as a object i.e typeof == 'object'. would love see you advice on that

Comment: @GregL sandbox link for your reference https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-rubin-yy2cyy?file=/src/index.js

Comment: I have shared the code sandbox and my research so why do people have to comment for not did an effort in research. If you find something unclear please comment down. we are humans who can mistakes not everyone is an expert to raise questions

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution. below is the link for code sandbox for the
https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-rubin-yy2cyy?file=/src/index.js:0-213same

```
 const suggestions = [
      {
        id: 1,
        person1: {
          id: "1",
          firstname: "test1",
          lastname: "singh",
          address: {
            state: "maharashtra"
          },
          attributeId: "fhgfgh"
        }
      }
    ];

const typeList = ["string", "number", "boolean"];

const getLabelValue = (itemList, initalArr, parentId) => {
  if (Array.isArray(itemList)) {
    itemList.forEach((currentItem, idx) => {
      const id = parentId ? `${parentId}.${idx}` : idx;
      if (typeList.includes(typeof currentItem)) {
        initalArr.push({
          title: id,
          value: id
        });
      } else {
        getLabelValue(currentItem, initalArr, id);
      }
    });
  } else {
    let keys = Object.keys(itemList);
    keys.forEach((currentKey) => {
      let currentItem = itemList[currentKey];
      const id = parentId ? `${parentId}.${currentKey}` : currentKey;
      if (typeList.includes(typeof currentItem)) {
        initalArr.push({
          title: id,
          value: id
        });
      } else {
        getLabelValue(currentItem, initalArr, id);
      }
    });
  }
  return initalArr;
};

console.log(">>>>>>>>>", getLabelValue(suggestions, [], ""));
```